# HDF5: what happens if the Fletcher32 checksum filter fails upon data input?

Tags: c++, c, fortran, hdf5

HDF5 supports various filters to be specified for the output data pipeline, in particular various compression algorithms and a Fletcher32 checksum.

On data input, the HDF5 library automatically detects any filters that have been applied to the data on file and applies the inverse filters (de-compression), without any action required by the user.

However, in the extensive (and somewhat confusing) HDF5 [documentation](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/index.html), I couldn't find any mentioning of the consequences of an incorrect checksum detected whilst reading.

I tagged this as `c`, `fortran`, and `c++`, as I'd be happy for the answer for either API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to mentioned in the documentation at all, but this [design spec](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc_resource/H5Checksum/EDC_spec.htm) for the Fletcher32 filter says that the user can supply a callback function to handle failure (i.e. an incorrect checksum). If no callback function is supplied,

> the write and read processes will fail if the Error-detecting code is enabled and finds error in the data.

This means that the return value of `H5Dread`, say, will be negative.

Once you have applied the Fletcher32 filter (with, e.g. [`H5Pset_fletcher32`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetFletcher32)), you can set the callback with [`H5Pset_filter_callback`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetFilterCallback). The callback function has to match the prototype:

```
typedef H5Z_cb_return_t (H5Z_filter_func_t) (H5Z_filter_t filter_id, void *buf, size_t buf_size, void *op_data)
```

and return either `H5Z_CB_FAIL` or `H5Z_CB_CONT`.This way, you can specify exactly what happens when the checksum fails.

There's a very ugly example of how to use all this in the appendix to the [design spec](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc_resource/H5Checksum/EDC_spec.htm).